# Run gif on hover

Tags: jquery, html

I have been trying to run gif on hover and i have got some sort of success. Below is my code. Currently the gif run only on hover when mouse is pointed over image. How could i make it possible that image changes on hover when mouse pointer anywhere in the division.

script

```
var imageSwap = function () {
var $this = $(this);
var newSource = $this.data('swap');
$this.data('swap', $this.attr('src'));
$this.attr('src', newSource);}$(function () {   '.playgif').hover(imageSwap, imageSwap);});
```

Code

```
<div class="col-sm-4 thumb text-center animate">
  <h3 class="green">Punktuell</h3>
  <div class="image"><img data-swap="images/punktuell.gif" src="images/punktuell.jpg" /></div>
  <p class="last">Wir engagieren uns fokussiert in  <br>unterschiedlichen Bereichen, <br>z.B. in Form von Workshops,  <br>Zielgruppenstrategien oder<br> Trendanalysen.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your script makes no sense.

Comment: So , i am unknown to jquery but still i made it. I think this will make sense to you before commenting
http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Plugin-To-Play-Animated-GIF-On-Hover-gifPlayer.html

Comment: Just hover and mover the cursor. the gif stops in between.  Please confirm before giving answer from your end first

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. The gif doesn't stop when I move it around.

Answer (score 2):

Your script kinda makes no sense. You should use `mouseout` and `mouseover` events.

```js
$(function () {
  $(".playgif").hover(function () {
    var stat = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", $(this).find("img").data("swap"));
    $(this).find("img").data("swap", stat);
  })
});
```

```css
.image {background: #ccf;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4 thumb text-center animate playgif">
  <h3 class="green">Punktuell</h3>
  <div class="image"><img data-swap="https://media.giphy.com/media/bPWyTsy2huZji/giphy.gif" src="http://i.imgur.com/hLe61Hi.gif?1" /></div>
  <p class="last">Wir engagieren uns fokussiert in <br>unterschiedlichen Bereichen, <br>z.B. in Form von Workshops, <br>Zielgruppenstrategien oder<br> Trendanalysen.</p>
</div>
```

I have added a lightblue background to show you the coverage of `<div>`.

Comment: Bro i have been trying to make it run when entered in a div where 'playgif ' class is defined in the outer most division. Please let me know if that works. I made a change to script i added playgif instead if image class. Now it is causing error. And sorry for harsh comments :-)

Comment: @AnmolSandal Yes bro, that works. It's totally fine. We are cool. `:D` I really wanna help you out. `:D`

Comment: Bro one more thing it has been made perfect now I have removed mouse out from it. Works fine for me now :-)

Comment: I already have negative result  for the question i asked as i am unknown to jquery and i do seach for it most of the times when i get stuck. first approach is always to do it own and second is stackoverflow

Comment: @AnmolSandal What do you think? Is my answer still not right?

Comment: I made changes to it , So i dont think its completely right, but still it was due to your suggestion i made it to perfect :-)

Comment: @AnmolSandal You know what, you can edit my answer and make it like what you want and accept it. That's how Stack Overflow works right? `:)` Have a nice day.

Comment: If you don't mind could i have your emailid. Want to have few discussions if you agree

Comment: Yes, definately

Comment: @AnmolSandal Any luck?

Comment: I didn't got you what you actually meant to say

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `.hover()` it's deprecated in jQuery 3+. Use `'mouseleave mouseenter'` instead.

### Demo

```js
$('.thumb').on('mouseleave mouseenter', imgSwap);

function imgSwap(e) {
  var img = $(this).find('img');
  var png = `http://i.imgur.com/68lj2z6.png`;
  var gif = img.data('swap');
  img[0].src === png ? img[0].src = gif : img[0].src = png;
}
```

```css
.thumb {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4 thumb text-center animate">
  <h3 class="green">Punktuell</h3>
  <div class="image"><img data-swap="http://i.imgur.com/DheohWR.gif" src="http://i.imgur.com/68lj2z6.png" width='250' /></div>
  <p class="last">Wir engagieren uns fokussiert in <br>unterschiedlichen Bereichen, <br>z.B. in Form von Workshops, <br>Zielgruppenstrategien oder<br> Trendanalysen.</p>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use CSS for this? It is easier and simpler way to handle gif. Look at the code:

```
<style>
.Homer {
height:165px;
width:140px;
background: url('URL-of-static-image');
margin:auto; /*position the [div] on the center*/
}
/*this is the hover event trigger*/
.Homer:hover {
cursor:pointer; 
background:url('URL-of-animated-GIF');
}
</style>
```

And for the html:

```
<div class="Homer"></div>
```

Replace ** homer ** with your specific class.

Comment: Well, one reason would be scalability. This solution won't work if there are many images, right?

Comment: no, it will work but you have to use different class or you can use simple javascript to handle that

Comment: That's what I meant by scalability... `:)` Did you understand? Would you keep writing 1000 css classes with background image definitions for 1000 such instances? Temme?

Comment: you are right to some extent but it's also a way: and for using multiple images you need to add js but it will be very simple...

Comment: You seem to be a very good coder but just don't get overconfident as you seem to be sometimes. Sorry but i am angry too the way you answer.

Comment: simply target the siblings and add the class **homer** and on hover change the background image you want(gif) in that way you can do...well you are welcome :)

Comment: hey @praveen you don't have to write 1000 CSS class if you are familiar with js...

Comment: He he. That's why I took the JS path. You know, you don't need to do with CSS either, if you know how to use `attr()`.